# How to send systemd Start - Stop - Reload syslog messages to a file

Tags: systemd, logs, mysql

I'd like to send Start/Stop/Reload systemd messages to a specific file. Specifically, mysqld doesn't seem to send daemon start/stop messages to the `log-error` file, so I'd like to have... something in the log indicating success/failure.

I'm at a point now where I'm messing around with `ExecStartPost` and `ExecStopPost`, but there has to be a better way. [Inspiration here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/728231/getting-journald-logs-to-a-plain-text-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working nicely in `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "DATE=$(date --iso-8601=seconds); \
    PID=$(/usr/bin/systemctl show -p MainPID mysql |sed 's/MainPID=//'); \
    /usr/bin/echo $${DATE} '[systemd] Starting MySQL Server... PID:' $${PID} \
    >> /var/log/error-mysql.log"
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c "DATE=$(date --iso-8601=seconds); \
    PID=$(/usr/bin/systemctl show -p MainPID mysql |sed 's/MainPID=//'); \
    /usr/bin/echo $${DATE} '[systemd] Stopping MySQL Server... PID:' $${PID} \
    >> /var/log/error-mysql.log"
```

Outputs:

```
2022-03-18T08:59:18-04:00 [systemd] Starting MySQL Server... PID: 1166
2022-03-18T08:59:28-04:00 [systemd] Stopping MySQL Server... PID: 0
2022-03-18T08:59:46-04:00 [systemd] Starting MySQL Server... PID: 1216
2022-03-18T08:59:58-04:00 [systemd] Stopping MySQL Server... PID: 0
2022-03-18T08:59:59-04:00 [systemd] Starting MySQL Server... PID: 1263
```